# Regex to match css class name when multiple used

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to make a regex to find any element that has a specific class.

For example

```
<span class = "float">
```

For which I came up with this:

```
\s*class\s*=\s*('|")\s*float\s*('|")\s*
```

But then of course you can have multiple CSS declared

```
<span class = "float align cssnames">
```

I am not sure how you would make everything else optional.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe `\s*class\s*=\s*('|")[\w\s]*\bfloat\b[\w\s]*('|")\s*`?

In between the quotes it looks for `float` with a *word boundary* on either side, possibly surrounded by further word characters and/or spaces (i.e. other CSS classes).

Answer (score 0):

`Regex rgx = new Regex("\"float.*\"");`

Will match "float *anything here but ends with the closing quote*"

Answer (score 0):

This code will look for the class=" and " as a non matched anchor. Then it will take each of the attribute values found and put each of them into a named capture group called Assignements.

Then linq will extract out the just those named capture(s) and then look for a single "Float" item from the captured group and return true or false.

```
string data = @"<span class = ""float align cssnames"">";

string pattern = @"(?:class\s*=\s*\x22)((?<Assignments>[^\s\x22]+)(?:\s?))+(?:\x22)";

var containsFloat =
   Regex.Matches(data, pattern, RegexOptions.Multiline)
      .OfType<Match>()
      .Select(mt => mt.Groups["Assignments"].Captures
                                             .OfType<Capture>()
                                             .Select(c => c.Value))
      .SelectMany(assignments => assignments) // is an IEnumerable<string> = { "float", "align", "cssnames" } at this point
      .Any(assignment => assignment == "float"); // True!
```